# What's the correct method to simplify exponentials?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a sum of exponentials that I'd like to simplify. The issue is when I use `Simplify`, Mathematica loves to factor out one exponential factor. See below:
$$e^{-i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +\text{$\theta $1}+\text{$\theta $2})} \left((e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta )}+2 e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta )}+e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 (\beta +\gamma +\delta ))}+2 e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +2 \text{$\theta $1})}+e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 (\beta +\text{$\theta $1}))}\right....))$$

Otherwise, when I try to `Expand` it I get
$$e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta )-i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +\text{$\theta $1}+\text{$\theta $2})}+2 e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta )-i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +\text{$\theta $1}+\text{$\theta $2})}+e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 (\beta +\gamma +\delta ))-i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +\text{$\theta $1}+\text{$\theta $2})}+2 e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +2 \text{$\theta $1})-i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +\text{$\theta $1}+\text{$\theta $2})}+e^{i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 (\beta +\text{$\theta $1}))-i (d (\text{kx1}+\text{kx2})+2 \beta +\gamma +\delta +\text{$\theta $1}+\text{$\theta $2})}$$

Any help on how to "simplify" correctly would be greatly appreciated. Note, `Refine` does nothing in my case.

Comment: Posting executable *Mathematica* code for copy&paste would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking the expression you get when `Expand` is applied, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` work nicely if one isn't going to generalize it to much.

```
expr =  E^( I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2β) - I ( d(kx1 + kx2) +  2β + γ + δ + θ1 + θ2)) + 
      2 E^( I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2β + γ + δ) - I( d(kx1 + kx2) +  2β + γ + δ + θ1 + θ2)) + 
        E^( I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2(β + γ + δ)) - I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2β + γ + δ + θ1 + θ2)) + 
      2 E^( I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2β + γ + δ + 2θ1) - I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2β + γ + δ + θ1 + θ2)) + 
        E^( I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2(β + θ1)) - I( d(kx1 + kx2) + 2 β + γ + δ + θ1 + θ2));
```

We can apply `Simplify` :

```
Simplify[ expr]
```

[image]

or `FullSimplify`

```
FullSimplify[expr]
```

[image]

If we assume another conditions (the second argument of `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`) we 
can get a simpler expression, e.g. assuming `θ1 ==  θ2` and `γ + δ == 0` yields :

```
Simplify[ expr, θ1 == θ2 && γ + δ == 0]
```

> ```
> 3 + 4 E^(-2 I θ2)
> ```

**Edit 1**

Taking into account the comments beneath I could do the task in another way, since it seems you just don't like the factorizing effect of `Simplify` on the whole expression. 
Therefore we can write the expression in the `List` form, then simplify every term seperately and finally write the terms as a sum :

```
Plus @@ Simplify[ List @@ expr]
```

> ```
> E^(I ( γ + δ - θ1 - θ2)) + 2 E^(I ( θ1 - θ2)) + E^(-I ( γ + δ - θ1 + θ2)) 
> + 2 E^(-I (θ1 + θ2)) + E^(-I ( γ+ δ + θ1 + θ2))
> ```

or even better map `Simplify` over the expression, simply :

```
Simplify /@ expr
```

since it returns the same :

```
Plus @@ Simplify[List @@ expr] == Simplify /@ expr
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Edit 2**

There are many ways to do things in `Mathematica`, here is another useful one :

```
expr /. Power[a_, b_] :> Power[a, Simplify[b]]
```

or if you want to simplify only exponentials :

```
expr /. E^(a_) :> E^Simplify[a]
```

They return the results as mapping `Simplify` over the expression, e.g. :

```
Simplify /@ expr == expr /. Power[a_, b_] :> Power[a, Simplify[b]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Simplifies nicely to trig functions, if you actually type in \\[ImaginaryI] instead of i.

Comment: @Guillochon Do you mean when using `ExpToTrig`?

Comment: @CHM FullSimplify will actually convert to trig automatically, if it can.

Comment: @Guillochon I was asking because I get the same result when I use `FullSimplify` on `expr/. "i" -> \[ImaginaryI]`.

Comment: Here's the thing. I do NOT want it to factor out one of the exponentials. Secondly, my list of exponentials is really long, so FullSimplify would take a really long time. Let me clarify that all I wanted was basically to simplify each individual exponential, if that makes sense.

Comment: @lababidi First, you should ask a clear question with the expression you try to simplify in the Mathematica form. You should update your question to make it a constructive one. I updated my answer to the form you wanted.