# Mathematica rule to express exponentials as multiplication

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but it is a very simple question and I would imagine it shouldn't be terribly hard for someone that knows to answer.

I'm essentially trying to tell mathematica to *not* simplify

```
Exp[x] Exp[y] -> Exp[x+y]
```

I am using an add on package which is having a hard time with some replacement rules. So, the question is, is it possible to force mathematica to express `Exp[x] Exp[y]` as is and not simplify it?

A secondary question, which should just be an extension of the first, I would like `(Exp[x] Exp[y] )^2` to be replaced as `Exp[x]^2 Exp[y]^2` not `Exp[2x+2y]`! Or even being left as is is ok.

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution to try to fix the package instead? Is it publicly and freely available?

Comment: Hold[Exp[x] Exp[y]] is supposed to solve this problem, but I've not had much success with Hold[] or HoldForm[] for some reason. Maybe others can address this.

Comment: I'm asking because I don't think it's possible to prevent this simplification without `Hold`ing the expression, as Steve suggests.  But doing that might prevent the package from working with the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @Szabolcs you were right, the hold command restricts the package. The package is freely available, however, it interfaces in such a way to Singular which restricts this as a solution to the problem.

Comment: Is this [this package](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/Singular/)?

Comment: No it's actually StringVacua, available at http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/projects/Stringvacua. I will soon attempt to implement Leonid's solution and I'll report once I see how it works out

Comment: See this related question [What's the correct method to simplify exponentials?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/whats-the-correct-method-to-simplify-exponentials).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to execute your entire code in some dynamic environment, where certain simplification rules are permanently or temporarily blocked. Here is the generic environment generator:

```
ClearAll[withBlockedSymbols];
withBlockedSymbols[syms : {__Symbol}] :=
   Function[code, Block[syms, code], HoldAll];
```

We can now produce an environment generator specifically for `Exp`:

```
withBlockedExp = withBlockedSymbols[{Exp}]
```

Now, any code executed inside this wrapper, will not use the automatic simplification rules for `Exp`, which will be inert inside this wrapper. For example:

```
withBlockedExp[Hold[Evaluate[Exp[x] Exp[y]]]]

(* Hold[Exp[x] Exp[y]] *)

withBlockedExp[Hold[Evaluate[(Exp[x] Exp[y])^2]]]

(* Hold[Exp[x]^2 Exp[y]^2] *)
```

The only reason I needed to use `Hold@Evaluate` was to prevent the simplification happening after the execution exits `withBlockedExp`. `Hold@Evaluate@expr` allows us to preserve a final form of `expr` evaluated inside dynamic environment. If you have less trivial transformations, you will see the utility of `withBlockedExp` better, since you don't have to use `Hold` etc. for intermediate steps inside `withBlockedExp`.

Comment: Thank you, this actually answered my original question, however, I was wrong in thinking it would solve the issue I'm having with the interface to my package!

Comment: @Richard Well, too bad then. But thanks for the accept. And you can always ask more questions (as separate questions), until your problem hopefully gets resolved.