# Function to Expand exponentials

Tags: functions

Is there a function similar to `PowerExpand` which expand exponentials? This would, for example, take

```
Exp[5(a + b)]
```

and return

> ```
> Exp[5a]*Exp[5b].
> ```

Comment: `Exp[5 a + 6 b] /. Exp[Plus[a_, b_]] :> CenterDot @@ {Exp[a], Exp[b]}`, which outputs $e^{5 a}\cdot e^{6 b}$, is one simple way to go. Making it correctly work in all cases might take some tinkering, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Besides given answers take a look at [What's the correct method to simplify exponentials?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/whats-the-correct-method-to-simplify-exponentials/8504#8504)

Answer (score 5):

The desired representation will automatically simplify when evaluated

```
Exp[5 a]*Exp[5 b]
```

[image]

To get and maintain the desired factored form requires any of several methods of holding the evaluation. As suggested by DumpsterDoofus, one approach is to use an unassigned operator. A slightly modified version of this approach:

```
expr = Exp[5 (a + b)];

f = CenterDot @@ (Exp /@ List @@
       (Log[#] // PowerExpand // Expand)) &;

invf = # /. CenterDot -> Times &;

expr2 = expr // f
```

[image]

Using the inverse

```
expr2 // invf
```

[image]

```
% // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This could also be a case where the version-10 command [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) may be useful. Before inserting an inactive version of `Exp`, I also split up exponents consisting of sums by temporarily replacing powers of `E` with a function `exp` that only implements the desired multiplicative property. To cast these replacements in the form of a function `expExpand`, we have to make sure the expression `expr` provided as its argument is not touched in any way. That's what the `HoldAllComplete` attribute is for:

```
ClearAll[expExpand, exp];
exp[x_Plus] := Times @@ exp /@ x

SetAttributes[expExpand, HoldAllComplete];

expExpand[expr_] := 
 ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. E^x_ :> exp[x]] /. exp -> Inactive[Exp]

expExpand[1/2 (E^(5 a) E^(7 b + 8 c + z)) + 1/(1 + E^(4 a))]
```

[image: inactive]

The expression is now displayed in the desired form, with the inactive `Exp` in a different color. You can then do `Activate` to get the expression to be returned to its canonical form if desired.

Comment: It works for my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Times is converted internally to power because Times is not a canonical form.
I would also suggest the following:

```
r=Dot @@ Exp /@ Level[(Exp[5 (a + b + c)] // ExpandAll), {2}]
(*E^(5 a).E^(5 b).E^(5 c)*)
```

if you want to bring back the result,then:

```
Times @@ r
(*E^(5 a + 5 b + 5 c)*)
```