# How to simplify this sums of exponentials?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

I got expressions that look like
$$
\frac{1}{2} \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i r x} \left[\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i r x} \left(1 + \mathrm e^{-2\mathrm i x}\right)^r + \left(1 + \mathrm e^{2\mathrm i x}\right)^r\right]
$$
and I want Mathematica to return $ 2^r\cos^rx $.

I tried `Assumptions -> x > 0 && r > 0` and other things but nothing seems to give me this obvious answer.
$x$ is a real number and $r$ is an integer.

Comment: This is colsely related [What's the correct method to simplify exponentials?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/whats-the-correct-method-to-simplify-exponentials/8504#8504)

Answer (score 3):

A roundabout way at arriving at the result.

```
expr = 1/2 E^(-I r x) (E^(2 I r x) (1 + E^(-2 I x))^r + (1 + E^(2 I x))^r);
```

Calculating a sequence for integer values of `r`

```
seq = Table[expr // FullSimplify, {r, 1, 5}]

(* {2 Cos[x], 4 Cos[x]^2, 8 Cos[x]^3, 16 Cos[x]^4, 32 Cos[x]^5} *)
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence

```
expr2 = FindSequenceFunction[seq, r] // Simplify

(* 2^r Cos[x]^r *)
```

Verifying that the expressions are equal for integer `r`

```
Assuming[Element[r, Integers], expr == expr2 // FullSimplify]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another kind of workaround:

```
expr = 1/2 E^(-I r x) (E^(2I r x) (1+E^(-2I x))^r+(1+E^(2I x))^r);

ExpToTrig[Simplify[Expand[expr] /. a_^(p_ q_) b_^p_ -> (a^q b)^p]]
```