# Simplifying expressions after expanding

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I am totally new to Mathematica, so if this is a simple googleable question, I am sorry

I have this expression:
$\left(e^{i \text{p1} x}-e^{-i \text{p1} x}\right) \left(e^{i \text{p2} x}-e^{-i \text{p2} x}\right) \left(e^{i \text{p3} x}-e^{-i \text{p3} x}\right) \left(e^{i \text{p4} x}-e^{-i \text{p4} x}\right)
$

```
 (Exp[I*p1 *x] - Exp[-I*p1 *x]) (Exp[I*p2 *x] - Exp[-I*p2 *x]) (Exp[I*p3 *x] - Exp[-I*p3 *x]) (Exp[I*p4 *x] - Exp[-I*p4 *x])
```

I want to see it as a sum of $e^{iax}$ terms. `Expand` does that, but it gives:
[image]
which could be further simplified as you can see by looking at it. How do I change these terms with minus signs(for eg, $p1-p2+p3-p4$) in the exponential and hence shorter?

Comment: Take a look at [What's the correct method to simplify exponentials?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/whats-the-correct-method-to-simplify-exponentials/8504#8504)

Comment: Did you try `FullSimplify`?

Comment: With `Expand` you get $e^{-i p_1 x-i p_2 x-i p_3 x-i p_4 x}-e^{i p_1 x-i p_2 x-i p_3 x-i p_4 x}-\cdots-e^{-i p_1 x+i p_2 x+i p_3 x+i p_4 x}+e^{i p_1 x+i p_2 x+i p_3 x+i p_4 x}$. With `FullSimplify` you get $16 \sin \left(p_1 x\right) \sin \left(p_2 x\right) \sin \left(p_3 x\right) \sin \left(p_4 x\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[p[n_]] := Subscript[p, n]

expr[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Product[Exp[I*p[k]*x] - Exp[-I*p[k]*x], {k, 1, n}] 

expr[4] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
expr[4] // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

```
(expr[4] // Expand) /. E^x_ :> E^(Simplify[x])
```

[image]

Or,

```
% === Map[Simplify, expr[4] // Expand, {2}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the last part of your answer.